# Oracle/SQL Query in the TFS Build Definition

Tags: sql, oracle, tfs, continuous-integration, build-definition

I would like to introduce CI Testing in one of my Webservice project with Newman. So once the build is ready, the cmd newman script will be executed for the validation.

My main objective here is to compare the DB values (SQL/Oracle) with the JSON Response body. Currently I am exporting the DB Query results to a CSV file and validating the same against the JSON response via Postman.

My Question is,

1. Is there any way we can create a cmd build definition in TFS for exporting the query result to a specified folder in a CSV format. (A command to export Oracle/SQL query to csv would be fine)
2. Can you please suggest me any other possible way to do it in an automated way to generate a CSV file from DB and add this in the build definition before the newman tool initiation. (Like VB Script file added into the build definition)

Thanks much in advance.

Comment: You can build a generic CSV converter in PL/SQL like [this one](http://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/refcursor-to-csv.shtml). I don't really know anything about TFS CI automation though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could still use NewMan PostMan in TFS build pipeline.

If you are working on TFS2017 and above, you could directly use this 3-rd party extension-- [Newman the cli Companion for Postman](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=carlowahlstedt.NewmanPostman)

[image]

If you are working on TFS2015, it's also easy to invoke newman tool in vNext build. You only need to add two build steps: `npm` and `Command Line`:

[image]

[image]

More detail steps please take a look at this blog: [Postman – Continuous Integration with TFS/VNext Builds](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=carlowahlstedt.NewmanPostman)

Comment: Hello Patrick, Thanks for your detailed information. I know I can use Newman in the build definitions. Inorder to validate the Json Response i need to create a data file from the SQL/Oracle DB as CSV file and place it in the Postman collection file location. So that the file will be taken by Newman and validate my Json response against the Data file which we have fetched from the DB. Is there any way to add a command Line to run the Oracle/SQL query to export the data from DB to the desired location. Then this data will be taken by newman during the run

Answer (score 0):

If you are not too deep into the implementation of the product, a more efficient way to compare data in oracle it within the db. You can search with flexibility.  Oracle can now load or select data in json format too. 
Since you need to connect to the DB to extract data, I am guessing this product is in a connected environment.

Comment: Thanks for the update Vijay. As you said for loading the Json format in Oracle and compare the data, we can do that. However we prefer the validation more like a CI way also we have SQL databases as well. So I think the exporting to CSV from DB source would be preferable

Answer (score 0):

You can add a powershell script task before newman to export the query result:

```
$SQLquery = 'Select * From xxx'
$queryresult = invoke-sqlcmd -query $SQLquery -serverinstance "SQLServer" -database 'dbname' 
$queryresult |export-csv "D:\paht\file.csv" -notypeinformation
```